# I'm trying to get the user to input numbers into an ArrayList. If the user enters 0, sum and average the numbers

Tags: java, arraylist, sum, average

This program asks users to input numbers which populates an array list. If the user inputs a 0, then the program sums all of the previous numbers inputted and averages them. It's not working for me, so how could I make this work?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Calculation {
    static Toolkit tools = new Toolkit();
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        double average = 0.0;
        double sum = 0;
        int i =0;
        int num = 0;
        int nElements = 0;
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter value: ");
        num = console.nextInt();
        while(num != 0) {
            value.add(new Integer(num));
        }

        for(i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
             sum += value.size();
        }
        average = sum / value.size();
        System.out.println("Number of values read: " + value.size());
        System.out.println("Values sum: " + sum + "Values average: " + average);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: After `num = console.nextInt();`, it's impossible for the user to enter any new values because you never prompt them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read inside the loop, here you have:

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {
     double average = 0.0;
     double sum = 0;
     int i =0;
     int num = 0;
     int nElements = 0;
     Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

     ArrayList<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     System.out.println("Enter value: ");
     num = console.nextInt();

     while(num != 0) {
         value.add(new Integer(num));
         num = console.nextInt();
     }

     for(i = 0; i < value.size(); i++) {
         sum += value.get(i);
     }
     average = sum / value.size();
     System.out.println("Number of values read: " + value.size());
     System.out.println("Values sum: " + sum + " Values average: " + average);
     System.exit(0);
}
```